# Usage of SQLiteDatabase.query()

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a `list view` with a `checkbox` to display `sale invocies`. when user is selecting checkboxes, i'm adding `sale_id` of selected invoices to `ArrayList<String>`.

Now i want to use data in this `ArrayList<String>` in `query()` method in `SQLiteDatabase`. I want to get invoice details using `sale ids` in `ArrayList`. size of `ArrayList` is not static.

how could i build query using data in `ArrayList` with `query()` method in `SQLiteDatabase` ?

Comment: PL make sure!! To get more help from community, you should post your code snip instead theory only.

Comment: @RDC don't think about `listview` in my app. just think about `ArrayList`. i'm having an `ArrayList` with `sale ids`. i want to use that sale ids in `query() method`. there is no code snippets to place here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my question. modified `stack_ved`s code as below.

```
String clause = ""; 

for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {

           String sales_id = checkedItems.get(i); 
            if(i == 0)
            clause += "SALES_ID = '" + sales_id "'";
            else
            clause += " OR SALES_ID = '" + sales_id "'";
    }
```

Replace `||` with `OR`

AND

```
Cursor c = database.query("TABLE_NAME", COLUMN_NAMES, clause, null,
                null, null, null);
```

Comment: great Bishan, good to know . could you please mark it answered, it would really be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ArrayList consists of all the checked items, iterate it through a loop and create a where clause. armed with this where clause we can fire a command on the SQLiteDatabase. Code would go something like below!

`ArrayList<String> checkedItems = ...//` load it with checked items from the list

//loop through
   `String clause = "";`
    `for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {`

```
       String sales_id = checkedItems.get(i); 
        if(i == 0)
        clause += "SALES_ID = '" + sales_id "'";
        else
        clause += " || SALES_ID = '" + sales_id "'";
```

}

// run the database sqlite query command

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SALES_TABLE  WHERE clause");
```

Comment: can't use `query()` as above

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase mdb = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();//SQLiteOpenHelper

/**
         * Get invoice details information
         * @param sale_id
         * @return
         */
        public Cursor getInvoiceDetails(int sale_id){
            String invoiceQuery= "SELECT " +
                                      " invoice._id," +
                                      " invoice.date," +
                                      " invoice.details " +
                                      " FROM " +
                                  TABLE_INVOICE                               
                                      " WHERE " +
                                      " invoice._id = " + sale_id;

            Log.d(TAG, "getInvoiceInfo: " + invoiceQuery);
            return mdb.rawQuery(invoiceQuery,null);
        }
```

Comment: there are more than one id. user can select more than one at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query as following:

```
public Cursor get_details (int id) {
        c = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table where id = "+id,null);
        return c;
        }
```

you only  write in listener your checkbox

```
ArrayList.add(id)
```

and when you want display details   you can get id as

```
for( i=0 ; i<ArrayList.size();i++){
    int id=ArrayList.get(0)
     get_details(id);
}
```

Comment: there are more than one id. user can select more than one at once.

Comment: assume there are 3 sale ids. according to your code, programe call `get_details(id);` 3 times. that means programe return `3 Cursors`. that is not what i want. i want to return on Cursor with details of 3 sale ids.

Comment: then I think is better you use way of stack_ved in below